# EKS auto-scaling with safe-to-evict=false pods scheduling behaviour

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

What is the EKS scheduler behavior in case of using:

```yaml
cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict=false
```

and autoscaling policies based on memory usage?

Let's say there is a cluster of 10 nodes, and on one node there is only one pod marked with `safe-to-evict=false` annotation which uses very low resources. This means it can possibly be rescheduled to other nodes (assume there are resources) so the 10th node could be removed by autoscaling policy. Will that happen? Or will the node be locked because of this one pod?